# Socket implementation is showing problem in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

On implementing the socket.io-client in my project it is showing an error and the connection status is false.

This is the code of socket.

```
 socket = io('url', {
    transports: ['websocket']
 })
 console.log(socket)
```

and I am using the socket version

```
 "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
```

But the console is showing

```
 It seems you are trying to reach a Socket.IO server in v2.x with a v3.x client, but they are not compatible (more information here: https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the socket.io version for the client and server such that the versions match and are compatible?

Comment: Yes, I Changed version to @1.7.4 now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Version from

```
"socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
```

To

```
"socket.io-client": "^1.7.4",
```

And Changed

```
import {io} from "socket.io-client
```

To

```
import io from "socket.io-client
```